# JQuery clone image reloads from server

Tags: jquery

When i use the following code to clone images from the page and append to a div, they get reloaded from the server. Is this expected behaviour? I am using FF 9. Thanks

```
var  modal = $('<div id="modal"></div>');
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).clone().appendTo(modal);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you clone the image, you create a new `<img>` tag, which is rendered like any new `<img>` tag would be. Most browsers would make a request when they see a new `<img>` tag, if the server did not specify any caching behavior for the image to which the tag points.

Comment: @Shomz, a way would be to specify caching behavior from the server, such as expiration date, so the client would know that it can keep the image in cache for a certain period. This applies to even if you don't clone the image, since it's the expected behavior of the browser to not request an image from the server if the server explicitly stated that the image can be cached for a certain period of time.

Comment: That was it.. thanks Radu. I set the expires for the images and they get cached and not reloaded when cloned.