# Check what image was loaded in HTML picture element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code in my app:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(max-width: 1300px)" srcSet={src.img['1']} />
    <source media="(max-width: 1599px)" srcSet={src.img['2']} />
    <source media="(max-width: 2049px)" srcSet={src.img['3']} />
</picture>
```

is it possible programmatically to check which of these images was loaded by browser in picture element? I have to use that image once again (now I use img['1'] by default in tooltip) but I want to avoid loading image one more time.

Comment: A solution would be to set the expiratio ndate from your image, then clone it. You should take a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365527/jquery-clone-image-reloads-from-server

Comment: The is a property current src : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366100/when-using-picture-source-and-srcset-how-check-which-src-was-loaded-img-src-i

Answer (score 1):

Include the `<img>` tag inside `<picture>` and check its `currentSrc` property.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I just open the console and then put this code in there.

```
console.log( img.src )
```

Remember that although you may use modern images like WebP with a JPG fallback, if WebP is supported it will not fall back.

Also you need to choose the element first or you will get image undefined.